# JFileChooser showOpenDialog method not working with ActionListener

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I have been trying to follow these set of Java tutorials from this website

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java.html

However the tutorials are in Netbeans and I am using Eclipse.

Till now there has been no difficulties until now.
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/opening_files.html

In the given tutorial using JFileChooser to open files through a JMenuItem called 'Open' is shown. However when i use the code given in the website the following error occurs

The method showOpenDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})

This is the code for which the error is occuring.

```
    JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int returnVal = db.showOpenDialog(this);
        }
    });
```

So, my question is, what should i change in the above code stub to be able to use the file chooser?

If you want to view the entire code, i will put it in on your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meaning of the error: the method `showOpenDialog` requires a parameter of type `Component` but is being called with an `ActionListener`. More exactly, the given parameter is of an anonymous class implementing `ActionListener` and not a `Component`:

```
new ActionListener()  { ... }
```

inside the methods declared where I used `. . .` the keyword `this` points to the instance of that anonymous class.

See the documentation of [`showOpenDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-java.awt.Component-), it requires a parent or `null`:

> Pops up an "Open File" file chooser dialog. Note that the text that 
>   appears in the approve button is determined by the L&F.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> parent - the parent component of the dialog, can be null; see showDialog for details
> ```

And the relevant documentation of [`showDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.String-):

> The parent argument determines two things: the frame on which the open 
>   dialog depends and the component whose position the look and feel should 
>   consider when placing the dialog. 
>   ...
>   If the parent is null, then the dialog depends on no visible window, and 
>   it's placed in a look-and-feel-dependent position such as the center of 
>   the screen.

Usually the passed parameter is the `JFrame` or `JPanel` that should *visually contain* the dialog, but it can be `null`:

```
    int returnVal = db.showOpenDialog(null);
```